# Send email to each of the mail addresses saved in a column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have list of email addresses on column D. I am trying to send mail to each of them using Outlook template (.oft) saved on a path.

It pops up a single email to the last email address on column D.

When I try to debug, it give me "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)".

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim oEMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Macro\OutlookTemplate.oft")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DUFFF")

    With ws
        lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(4))

        For i = 2 To lRow

            With OutMail
                .To = ws.Range("D" & i).Value
                .Subject = "Blah Blah"
                .HTMLBody = OutMail.HTMLBody
                '.Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\Sample.Txt"
                .Display
                
            End With
            
            'On Error GoTo 0
            'Set OutApp = Nothing
        Next i
    End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Use CDO Mail instead of trying to automate outlook from Excel. This way it just sends all the mail magically. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm

Comment: Rather than using `.Display`, use `.Save` or `.Send`

Comment: @Applecore I don't know how that helps me? My intention is to send a mail to each email address in Column D. Not a single email to all of the email address.

Comment: The `With OutMail....End With` piece of code creates a single e-mail. You therefore need to either send it or save it before moving to create the next one.

Comment: Tried, it still sent only one email. Any more suggestion I can try?

Comment: Do a `Debug.Print` for `lRow` to see what value that is set to be.

Comment: You need to move `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate()` into the `For i=2 to lRow` loop so that it is created in each loop.

Comment: lRow give 5. Moving Set outMail as you described worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Got there in the end!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On help from @Applecore, if it helps anyone, below is the working code to send email to each row from a column using Outlook Template (.oft):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim oEMail As Object

    
    Workbooks("AAA.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("BBB").Activate
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBB")

    With ws
        lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(4))

        For i = 2 To lRow
        If ws.Range("I" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Macro\ Template.oft")
    
            With OutMail
    
                .To = ws.Range("D" & i).Value
                .Subject = "Blah Blah"
                .HtmlBody = Replace(OutMail.HtmlBody, "CandiName", ws.Range("B" & i).Value)
                '.Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\Sample.Txt"
                .Display
                
            End With
        End If
            
          
    Next i
    End With
MsgBox ("Mailed Successfully!")
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is the answer please mark it with the green checkmark on the left. That closes the Q and gives you points.

Comment: No, you don't have to vote. It's a grey checkmark that turns green when you click it. You absolutely can answer your own question. We do it all the time.

Comment: you are right! did it now. Maybe my rep is low, I could not do it before.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `.To` every loop. Thus, only the last one would be left at the end.

You need to concatenate with `;` between the addresses.

Like this:

```
.To = .To & ";" & ws.Range("D" & i).Value
```

Comment: it append ".To" in a single mail. What I wanted was to send them individual mail.